# IOHIDDeviceSetReport method doesn't accept UnsafeRawPointer type in Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

IOHIDDeviceSetReport method doesn't accept UnsafeRawPointer type
the method signature is :

```
IOHIDDeviceSetReport(<#T##device: IOHIDDevice##IOHIDDevice#>, <#T##reportType: IOHIDReportType##IOHIDReportType#>, <#T##reportID: CFIndex##CFIndex#>, <#T##report: UnsafePointer<UInt8>##UnsafePointer<UInt8>#>, <#T##reportLength: CFIndex##CFIndex#>)
```

thta allows to give as input only a UnsafePointer type, but in swift 3 there I can ony use UnsafeRawPointer type.
Does anybody have any idea how to get a UnsafeRawPointer from UnsafeRawPointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods for migrating an UnsafeRawPointer to UnsafePointer. The one I've used the most has been:

```
UnsafePointer.withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_)
```

You should be able to use the above, or one of the other methods mentioned in the following page to do what you need:

https://swift.org/migration-guide/se-0107-migrate.html

Comment: so for example if you have NSData data with bytes, how do you get an UnsafePointer?

Comment: IOHIDDeviceSetReport(HidInterface, kIOHIDReportTypeOutput, reportId, (data as NSData).bytes.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: data.length), data.length);

Answer (score 0):

If the report is given as a `Data` value then you can use the
`withUnsafeBytes()` method to access the bytes.
The closure is called with a `UnsafePointer<T>` argument pointing
to the bytes. Here the compiler can infer `T` as `UInt8` automatically
from the type of the `report` parameter:

```
let result = data.withUnsafeBytes {
    IOHIDDeviceSetReport(device, type, reportID, $0, data.count)
}
```